# Better way to describe tears

Tags: phrase-choice

*‘The tears welled up in pair of her eyes.’* I don’t really know how to phrase it. It looks a bit awkward. What is another way to write it?

Comment: ‘The tears welled up in the corners of her eyes.’

Comment: *The tears welled up in **both of** her eyes.*

Comment: Are you concerned with the plurality of the two eyes or with the location of the tears relative to each eye?

Answer (score 0):

“teardrops began to flow from the corners of her (color) eyes”